# Getting the previous Non Null value columnname

Tags: sql, db2

I have a row in db2 with the values like :

```
LEVEL1,LEVEL2,LEVEL3,LEVEL4,LEVEL5,LEVEL6,LEVEL7,LEVEL8,  NAME
   AB     BC      CD     EF        GH     NULL     NULL    EGH      TEST
```

The parent of level2 is level 1 and the parent of level 4 is level 3 .
Eg:

```
BC --> AB(Parent)
CD -->  BC(Parent)
```

But the parent of EGH  is GH the last nonnull field .

I have written a query to get the code,parent column .

```
select distinct(LEVEL2), LEVEL1 as parent from tablename;
```

But this does not work out in all cases as in the case of Level8 .

Is there any query to do so.or can this be acheived through PL/SQL. I am a noob with PL/SQL.

The main doubt is how to get the "ColumnName " so that it can be replaced in the query .

```
select distinct(LEVEL2), LEVEL1 as parent from tablename;
```

I need to get the columnname LEVEL7 or LEVEL6 whichever has the last non null value.

Comment: `DISTINCT`is ***NOT*** a function. `distinct (LEVEL2)` is useless. `distinct` works on **all** columns of the select list.

Comment: @jpw: ah, thanks I overlooked the "DB2" in the text. The PL/SQL tag is irrelevant as far as I can tell as no stored procedures are involved here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `coalesce` function to return the first non-null value in a list of items:

```
select distinct LEVEL8, COALESCE(level7, level6, level5) as parent 
from tablename;
```

In your example this would return `GH` from `LEVEL5`.

See the [reference documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_coalesce.dita).